# Why MATLAB Coder can't build MEX?

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I have a problem. MATLAB Coder doesn't work properly with one of my projects. At Check For Issues state it generates error "MEX build failed". But it doesn't generate any error message. Target Build Log is empty. When I try to do the same on the another PC with the same settings, there is no errors and MEX building is successfull. On the first PC MATLAB R2017a is installed, on the second PC MATLAB R2016b is installed. Why MEX building fails on the first PC and how can I define what error was occured?

Comment: You certainly need to give more information. Is this with any mex, or with some specific code or library? which compilers are you using? Different MATLAB versions have sometimes different compatible compilers.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have this problem with only one MATLAB function. It doesn't contain any specific features, any toolboxes etc. I have MinGW64 v4 on both PCs. But I think it doesn't matter, because I can generate code without compilers installed (with deactivated "generate makefile" option).

Comment: *Which* MATLAB function? Try always to add a [mcve] to your questions, it help us help you

Comment: @AnderBiguri
I mean m-function, that I wrote.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Let this function be function A. This function calls function B, that I wrote too. Function B contains operator " \ ". If I comment the string with this operator, then mex builds successfully. If I write " 0 \ 0 " I have no problem too. But If I write "zeros(16,17) \ zeros(16,1)", I have "MEX build failed" error. On the second PC all cases works correctly.

Comment: @AnderBiguri In addition, if I try to generate code just for function B, it builds MEX without any problem in all above mentioned cases.

Comment: @AnderBiguri If I activate "stop on errors" option in the editor, when MEX build fails matlab stops in debug mode and shows some variables in workspace. I have no idea what these vatiables means.